# How to make an array of key value pair objects from nested objects api json data

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am building a react native app (JavaScript) I want to create an array of Key value pairs Book objects from the fetched array of nested Book objects returned by the api.

This is the Book model class:

```
class Book {
  constructor(id, name, numberOfPages, createdAt, document, subCategory, level, subject, coreAreaOfStudy, languageOfInstruction) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    this.document = document;
    this.subCategory = subCategory;
    this.level = level;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.coreAreaOfStudy = coreAreaOfStudy;
    this.languageOfInstruction = languageOfInstruction;
  }
}

The fetched api Books' data looks like this (with nested objects):
let resData = [
  {
    author_name: "Varial",
    coreAreaOfStudy: [
      {
        abbreviation: "D",
        id: 2,
        name: "MATHEMATIQUES ET SCIENCES DE LA VIE ET DE LA TERRE",
      },
    ],
    coverPicture:
      "http://192.168.100.65:8000/media/Books_Cover_Pictures/images.jpg",
    createdAt: "2021-02-07T10:00:49.589894Z",
    document:
      "http://192.168.100.65:8000/media/Books/DOHONE_-_API_-_PAYIN_-_Contrat_-_fr_-_2.2.pdf",
    id: 1,
    languageOfInstruction: {
      abbreviation: "Fr",
      flag: null,
      id: 1,
      name: "Français",
    },
    level: [
      {
        abbreviation: "Tle",
        coreAreaOfStudy: [],
        id: 1,
        languageOfInstruction: 1,
        name: "Terminale",
        subject: [],
      },
    ],
    name: "Collection CIAM avec corrigés",
    numberOfPages: 7,
    subCategory: [
      {
        category: 1,
        id: 2,
        name: "Scolaire (Secondaire)",
      },
      {
        category: 1,
        id: 4,
        name: "Fascicule",
      },
    ],
    subject: [
      {
        abbreviation: "Maths",
        id: 1,
        name: "Mathématiques",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    author_name: " ",
    coreAreaOfStudy: [
      {
        abbreviation: "D",
        id: 2,
        name: "MATHEMATIQUES ET SCIENCES DE LA VIE ET DE LA TERRE",
      },
    ],
    coverPicture:
      "http://192.168.100.65:8000/media/Books_Cover_Pictures/406c8535c646f294c508ff5a1c3e281c.jpg",
    createdAt: "2021-02-08T22:38:01.397061Z",
    document:
      "http://192.168.100.65:8000/media/Books/Epreuve_danglais_Tle_-_Schoolest.pdf",
    id: 2,
    languageOfInstruction: {
      abbreviation: "Fr",
      flag: null,
      id: 1,
      name: "Français",
    },
    level: [
      {
        abbreviation: "1ere",
        coreAreaOfStudy: [],
        id: 3,
        languageOfInstruction: 1,
        name: "Seconde",
        subject: [],
      },
      {
        abbreviation: "1ere",
        coreAreaOfStudy: [],
        id: 4,
        languageOfInstruction: 1,
        name: "Première",
        subject: [],
      },
    ],
    name: "Bord bleu",
    numberOfPages: 30,
    subCategory: [
      {
        category: 1,
        id: 4,
        name: "Fascicule",
      },
    ],
    subject: [
      {
        abbreviation: "SVT",
        id: 2,
        name: "Science de la Vie et de la Terre",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

With the following code, I'm able to CONSOLE.LOG the list of Key value pairs from the nested api data:

```
resData.filter((item) => {
  iterateObject(item);
});

function iterateObject(obj) {
  for (prop in obj) {
    // console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", typeof obj[prop]);
    if (typeof obj[prop] == "string") {
      console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", obj[prop]);
    } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "number") {
      console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", obj[prop]);
    } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
      if (obj[prop].name) {
        console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", obj[prop].name);
      } else {
        for (const key in obj[prop]) {
          console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", obj[prop][key].name);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BUT I HAVE NOT BEEN ABLE SO FAR TO COME UP WITH AN ALGORITHM THAT LOOPS THROUGH THE API DATA AND PLACES THOSE PRINTED KEY VALUE PAIRS INTO AN ARRAY OF DISTINCT KEY VALUE PAIRS OBJECTS.

This is my expected output:

```
resData = [
  {
    author_name: "Varial Dassi",
    coreAreaOfStudy: ["MATHEMATIQUES ET SCIENCES DE LA VIE ET DE LA TERRE"],
    coverPicture: "http://192.168.100.65:8000/media/Books_Cover_Pictures/images.jpg",
    createdAt: "2021-02-07T10:00:49.589894Z",
    document:"http://192.168.100.65:8000/media/Books/DOHONE_-_API_-_PAYIN_-_Contrat_-_fr_-_2.2.pdf",
    id: 1,
    languageOfInstruction: "Français",
    level: ["Terminale"],
    name: "Collection CIAM avec corrigés",
    numberOfPages: 7,
    subCategory: ["Scolaire (Secondaire)", "Fascicule"],
    subject: ["Mathématiques"],
  },
  {
    author_name: " ",
    coreAreaOfStudy: ["MATHEMATIQUES ET SCIENCES DE LA VIE ET DE LA TERRE"],
    coverPicture:"http://192.168.100.65:8000/media/Books_Cover_Pictures/406c8535c646f294c508ff5a1c3e281c.jpg",
    createdAt: "2021-02-08T22:38:01.397061Z",
    document:"http://192.168.100.65:8000/media/Books/Epreuve_danglais_Tle_-_Schoolest.pdf",
    id: 2,
    languageOfInstruction: "Français",
    level: ["Seconde", "Première"],
    name: "Bord bleu",
    numberOfPages: 30,
    subCategory: ["Fascicule"],
    subject: ["Science de la Vie et de la Terre"],

  },
];
```

I HAVE TRIED THIS (AMONG OTHERS) IN VAIN:

```
loadedBooks = [];
function iterateObject(obj) {
  for (var i = 0, l = resData.length; i < l; i++) {
    for (prop in obj[i]) {
      // console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", typeof obj[i][prop]);
      if (typeof obj[prop] == "string") {
        console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", obj[prop]);
      } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "number") {
        console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", obj[prop]);
      } else if (typeof obj[prop] == "object") {
        if (obj[prop].name) {
          console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", obj[prop].name);
        } else {
          for (const key in obj[prop]) {
            console.log(prop.toUpperCase() + ": ", obj[prop][key].name);
          }
        }
      }
      loadedBooks.push(
        new Book(obj[i][prop].name ? obj[i][prop].name : obj[i][prop])
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The output is just an empty array like this: []

I have been on it for 3 days now without solution.
Can someone please assist me on this ?

Comment: Could you supply an expected output? :)

Comment: I have just edited it to supply The expected output.